# Firebase Functions: Support Global variable across functions

Tags: firebase, caching, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to cache most recent records (say last 24 hrs) in a http firebase function.
In a http firebase function (say fetchLastXRecords), I look for the record in cache (defined Global variable to store the records) if not found fetch from database and set cache.

Problem arises when I want to update any record of cache because this Global variable is not accessible by other firebase functions (could be real time database change triggers).

What could be a good approach to update the records in cache? May be I can invoke the caching http firebase function and pass the updated records? or I can store the updated records in database and later caching function look in database and update the cache records?

Comment: Cloud Functions should be stateless, as each may run on a separate instance. A cache is a valid approach, but you'll need to ensure it auto-initializes for each function call. I'm not sure what the problem with the global variable is, so please look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen seems I can't share an in memory object across functions. Any global variable (defined outside function scope) is for multiple invocation of single function only.

Comment: Cloud Functions does support global variables:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#stateless_functions

Answer (score 13):

In Cloud Functions, you have no ability to ensure that there is a global variable in your code that's accessible by your functions.  There are two things you need to know about how Cloud Functions works:

1. Under load, multiple server instances will be allocated to run your functions.  These server instances don't share any state.
2. Each of your functions is deployed to different server instances.  Two functions will never run on the same server instance.

As a result, if you have any values to share between functions, you should use a persistence mechanism, such as a database.  When your functions need to read and write a shared value, they should access the database.  Also, they should use some sort of atomic transaction to make sure that multiple concurrent reads and writes are safe.

Comment: yes Doug, can't cache in memory. Database looks only option.

Comment: Cloud Functions does support global variables:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#stateless_functions

Comment: @LaszloSchürg What that documentation is saying is that you have to use another product to share data across function invocations **that are running on different server instances**.  JavaScript globals are only accessible by function invocations running on the same instance. Cloud Functions itself does not have a facility for sharing across instances.  That's what my last paragraph is saying - you should use a persistence mechanism, such as a database.

Comment: True is that the scope/lifespan of the global variable is only per function instance, which you need to consider.
The documentation does have a recommendation regards caching: "Therefore, it is recommended to cache state across invocations in global scope where possible. Your function should be still prepared to work without this cache available as..."
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#function_instance_lifespan

Comment: @LaszloSchürg The key phrase here is "where possible".  The OP is asking about multiple functions that don't share a global scope.  In that case, a persistence mechanism is required to share data between invocations.

Comment: @DougStevenson what product/mechanism will be as fast an in-memory cache that can be shared across all instances? firestore takes 300-600ms while I need sub 5ms lookups