# How do I share information between functions on Firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am developing a project now in react-native and I integrated firebase to handle my data.
I am now working on the **index.js** file from the function.

So basically what I am trying to do is through the use of **.onCreate** functions retrieve the information of the user once it is created and use the same information in  **.onCreate** function for orders.

I tried to store my information on global variables but it doesn't work it appears as undefined.

Probably in the image it would be explained better.

[This is where i am having problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQW84.jpg)

```js
var username;

// ------------ USER DATA FUNCTION ------
exports.requestUserData = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/{autoGen}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => { 
    username = snap._data.name;
    console.log(` Username: ${username}`);
});


// ---- ORDERS FUNCTION -----
exports.sendEmail = functions.database.ref('/orders/{userId}/{orderId}/')  
    .onCreate((snap, context) => { 
    const userId = context.params.userId;
  // USERNAME IS WHAT I NEED TO GET TO USE IN THIS FUNCTION

        console.log(`THIS IS WHAT I AM EXPECTING TO GET! --> ${username}`);
```

EDIT: If it is not possible then could i make a request to a database within another function?

Thanks a lot for any help!!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. I also highly recommend studying [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it contains great guidance to maximize the chances that someone can help.

Comment: Thanks, just new in stackoverflow, I edited and include it in the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Functions: Support Global variable across functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687786/firebase-functions-support-global-variable-across-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions cannot share information through shared global variables.  Each function runs completely independently from each other and have no shared state.  You're going to have to find a way to share data by some other means, such as another location in the database.

I suggest watching this for more information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCpKxpIMg6o

Answer (score 0):

As Doug said, you can't share information between different Cloud Functions through global variables. The two functions run in different containers. But even if they ran on the same container, there's no guarantee that `requestUserData` would be invoked before `sendEmail`.

Instead, you'll need to read the username inside the `sendEmail` function with something like this:

var username;

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.database.ref('/orders/{userId}/{orderId}/')  
    .onCreate((snap, context) => { 
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    return snapshot.ref.root.child(`/users/${userId}/name`).once("value).then((nameSnapshot) => {
        const username = nameSnapshot.val();
        console.log(username);

        ... any code that needs the username
    });
});
```